# How to change currently selected date in TDateTimePicker control in another process by its HWND handle?

Tags: c++, c, delphi, winapi

I'm writing a custom module to work with a proprietary software. (That software has been discontinued and I do not have its source code.) My module will run as a separate process. Its goal is to automate an operation via this proprietary software. To do that I need to be able to select a specific date in the `TDateTimePicker` control. I know it's a Delphi control, but that's as far as my knowledge of Delphi/Pascal goes. I can find the `HWND` handle for this control though.

So my question -- is there a way to set a date in that control only by its handle from an outside process *(using WinAPIs)*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can send a [`DTM_SETSYSTEMTIME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761782.aspx) message to the DTP's `HWND`.  However, that message takes a pointer to a `SYSTEMTIME` record as a parameter, and that pointer MUST be valid in the address space of the process that owns the DTP control.

`DTM_SETSYSTEMTIME` is *NOT* auto-marshaled by Windows when sent across process boundaries, so if you take a pointer to a `SYSTEMTIME` owned by the sending process and send it as-is into the DTP process, that will not work. You MUST manually marshal the `SYSTEMTIME` data to the DTP process, for example:

```
uses
  ..., CommCtrl;

var
  Wnd: HWND;
  Pid: DWORD;
  hProcess: THandle;
  ST: TSystemTime;
  PST: PSystemTime;
  Written: SIZE_T;
begin
  Wnd := ...; // the HWND of the DateTimePicker control
  DateTimeToSystemTime(..., ST); // the desired date/time value

  // open a handle to the DTP's owning process...
  GetWindowThreadProcessId(Wnd, Pid);
  hProcess := OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_WRITE or PROCESS_VM_OPERATION, FALSE, Pid);
  if hProcess = 0 then RaiseLastOSError;
  try
    // allocate a SYSTEMTIME record within the address space of the DTP process...
    PST := PSystemTime(VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, nil, SizeOf(ST), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE));
    if PST = nil then RaiseLastOSError;
    try
      // copy the SYSTEMTIME data into the DTP process...
      if not WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, PST, @ST, SizeOf(ST), Written) then RaiseLastOSError;
      // now send the DTP message, specifying the memory address that belongs to the DTP process...
      SendMessage(Wnd, DTM_SETSYSTEMTIME, GDT_VALID, LPARAM(PST));
    finally
      // free the SYSTEMTIME memory...
      VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, PST, SizeOf(ST), MEM_DECOMMIT);
    end;
  finally
    // close the process handle...
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
  end;
end;
```

Now, with that said, there is another problem related specifically to `TDateTimePicker` (not to DTP controls in general).  `TDateTimePicker` **does not** use the [`DTM_GETSYSTEMTIME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761769.aspx) message to retrieve the currently selected date/time.  Its `Date`/`Time` properties simply return the current value of an internal `TDateTime` variable that gets updated when:

1. the `TDateTimePicker` is initially created, where the date/time is set to `Now()`.
2. its `Date`/`Time` property is assigned by the app, either in code or DFM streaming.
3. it receives a `DTN_DATETIMECHANGE` notification with a new date/time value.

In this situation, you want #3 to happen.  However, `DTN_DATETIMECHANGE` (which is based on [`WM_NOTIFY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775583.aspx)) is not generated automatically by `DTM_SETSYSTEMTIME`, so you have to fake it, but `WM_NOTIFY` **cannot be sent across process boundaries** (Windows will not allow it - Raymond Chen [explains a bit why](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/08/21/9877791.aspx)).  This is documented on MSDN:

> For Windows 2000 and later systems, the WM_NOTIFY message cannot be sent between processes.

So, you would have to inject some custom code into the DTP's owning process to send the `DTN_DATETIMECHANGE` within the same process as the DTP.  And injecting code into another process [is not trivial to implement](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4610/Three-Ways-to-Inject-Your-Code-into-Another-Proces).  However, in this particular case, there is a fairly simply solution, courtesy of David Ching:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/microsoft.public.vc.mfc/QMAHlPpEQyM/Nu9iQycmEykJ

> As others have pointed out, the pointer in LPARAM needs to reside in the same process as the thread that created hwnd ...  I have created a SendMessageRemote() API which uses VirtualAlloc, ReadProcessMemory, WriteProcessMemory, and CreateRemoteThread to do the heavy lifting ...
>
> http://www.dcsoft.com/private/sendmessageremote.h
>   http://www.dcsoft.com/private/sendmessageremote.cpp
>
> It is based on a great CodeProject article:
>  
>   http://www.codeproject.com/threads/winspy.asp.

Here is a Delphi translation of his code.  Note, I have tested it in 32-bit and it works, but I have not tested it in 64-bit.  You may have to tweak it when sending a message from a 32bit process to a 64bit process or vice versa, or if the target DTP is using an Ansi window instead of a Unicode window:

```
const
  MAX_BUF_SIZE = 512;

type
  LPFN_SENDMESSAGE = function(Wnd: HWND; Msg: UINT; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT; stdcall;

  PINJDATA = ^INJDATA;
  INJDATA = record
    fnSendMessage: LPFN_SENDMESSAGE;    // pointer to user32!SendMessage
    hwnd: HWND;
    msg: UINT;
    wParam: WPARAM;
    arrLPARAM: array[0..MAX_BUF_SIZE-1] of Byte;
  end;

function ThreadFunc(pData: PINJDATA): DWORD; stdcall;
begin
  Result := pData.fnSendMessage(pData.hwnd, pData.msg, pData.wParam, LPARAM(@pData.arrLPARAM));
end;

procedure AfterThreadFunc;
begin
end;

function SendMessageRemote(dwProcessId: DWORD; hwnd: HWND; msg: UINT; wParam: WPARAM; pLPARAM: Pointer; sizeLParam: size_t): LRESULT;
var
  hProcess: THandle;    // the handle of the remote process
  hUser32: THandle;
  DataLocal: INJDATA;
  pDataRemote: PINJDATA;    // the address (in the remote process) where INJDATA will be copied to;
  pCodeRemote: Pointer; // the address (in the remote process) where ThreadFunc will be copied to;
  hThread: THandle; // the handle to the thread executing the remote copy of ThreadFunc;
  dwThreadId: DWORD;
  dwNumBytesXferred: SIZE_T; // number of bytes written/read to/from the remote process;
  cbCodeSize: Integer;
  lSendMessageResult: DWORD;
begin
  Result := $FFFFFFFF;

  hUser32 := GetModuleHandle('user32');
  if hUser32 = 0 then RaiseLastOSError;

  // Initialize INJDATA
  @DataLocal.fnSendMessage := GetProcAddress(hUser32, 'SendMessageW');
  if not Assigned(DataLocal.fnSendMessage) then RaiseLastOSError;

  DataLocal.hwnd := hwnd;
  DataLocal.msg := msg;
  DataLocal.wParam := wParam;

  Assert(sizeLParam <= MAX_BUF_SIZE);
  Move(pLPARAM^, DataLocal.arrLPARAM, sizeLParam);

  // Copy INJDATA to Remote Process
  hProcess := OpenProcess(PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD or PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION or PROCESS_VM_OPERATION or PROCESS_VM_WRITE or PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, dwProcessId);
  if hProcess = 0 then RaiseLastOSError;
  try
    // 1. Allocate memory in the remote process for INJDATA
    // 2. Write a copy of DataLocal to the allocated memory
    pDataRemote := PINJDATA(VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, nil, sizeof(INJDATA), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE));
    if pDataRemote = nil then RaiseLastOSError;
    try
      if not WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, pDataRemote, @DataLocal, sizeof(INJDATA), dwNumBytesXferred) then RaiseLastOSError;

      // Calculate the number of bytes that ThreadFunc occupies
      cbCodeSize := Integer(LPBYTE(@AfterThreadFunc) - LPBYTE(@ThreadFunc));

      // 1. Allocate memory in the remote process for the injected ThreadFunc
      // 2. Write a copy of ThreadFunc to the allocated memory
      pCodeRemote := VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, nil, cbCodeSize, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
      if pCodeRemote = nil then RaiseLastOSError;
      try
        if not WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, pCodeRemote, @ThreadFunc, cbCodeSize, dwNumBytesXferred) then RaiseLastOSError;

        // Start execution of remote ThreadFunc
        hThread := CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, nil, 0, pCodeRemote, pDataRemote, 0, dwThreadId);
        if hThread = 0 then RaiseLastOSError;
        try
          WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);

          // Copy LPARAM back (result is in it)
          if not ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, @pDataRemote.arrLPARAM, pLPARAM, sizeLParam, dwNumBytesXferred) then RaiseLastOSError;
        finally
          GetExitCodeThread(hThread, lSendMessageResult);
          CloseHandle(hThread);
          Result := lSendMessageResult;
        end;
      finally
        VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, pCodeRemote, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
      end;
    finally
      VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, pDataRemote, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
  end;
end;
```

Now the code to manipulate the DTP becomes much simpler:

```
uses
  ..., CommCtrl;

var
  Wnd: HWND;
  Pid: DWORD;
  nm: TNMDateTimeChange;
begin
  Wnd := ...; // the HWND of the DateTimePicker control

  // get PID of DTP's owning process
  GetWindowThreadProcessId(Wnd, Pid);

  // prepare DTP message data
  nm.nmhdr.hwndFrom := Wnd;
  nm.nmhdr.idFrom := GetDlgCtrlID(Wnd); // VCL does not use CtrlIDs, but just in case
  nm.nmhdr.code := DTN_DATETIMECHANGE;
  nm.dwFlags := GDT_VALID;
  DateTimeToSystemTime(..., nm.st); // the desired date/time value

  // now send the DTP messages from within the DTP process...
  if SendMessageRemote(Pid, Wnd, DTM_SETSYSTEMTIME, GDT_VALID, @nm.st, SizeOf(nm.st)) <> 0 then
    SendMessageRemote(Pid, GetParent(Wnd), WM_NOTIFY, nm.nmhdr.idFrom, @nm, sizeof(nm));
end;
```

If all goes well, the `TDateTimePicker` will now update its internal `TDateTime` variable to match the `SYSTEMTIME` that you send to it.

Comment: You'd think that this could be done instead using automation. But it doesn't look like the control supports automation. Ho hum. I can't see an alternative to this.

Comment: Wow...this is just, wow.. When I start thinking I know something about  winapi I see things like this and realise I know nothing at all. I MUST play with those things

Comment: Most window messages that have pointer-based parameters are not auto-marshaled when passed across process boundaries.  Only certain system messages are, like `WM_TEXT`.  So you have to be very careful when sending messages with pointer parameters from one process to another. Consider a ListView control, for example. Not only do some of its messages take a pointer to a `LV_ITEM` record as parameter, but `LV_ITEM` itself also has its own pointers to data buffers.  So you have to manually allocate memory for those as well, when manipulating ListView items across process boundaries. Not fun.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Good info. Thanks! So what do you do if one of the parameters that is passed via `SendMessage` itself contains a pointer? How to get a value for that pointer?

Comment: @c00000fd: exactly how I showed. Use `VirtualAllocEx()` to allocate a memory block in the other process and get a pointer that is valid within the other process, then use `WriteProcessMemory()` to fill that memory with data (and `ReadProcessMemory()` to read data from that memory). So, if you have a pointer to an item that has a pointer to another item, you have two allocations (unless you merge them together).

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Going back to the original question, you know it's not yet a working solution. Interestingly enough, if I implement your code it changes the date in the `TDateTimePicker` control but then when I click OK in the target software it still tries to use the date that was originally there. I also tried doing it via plain `WM_SETTEXT` and with `DTM_SETSYSTEMTIME` and although the second method worked as yours, it still didn't change this behavior. I don't know those Delphi controls, could there be something else that I'm missing?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: You did it, my friend. Thanks! There's an issue with your `ThreadFunc` which I outlined in my separate post. But the rest works great.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on [Remy Lebeau's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28908137/843732), which pretty much gives a solution.

There are two issues with his `ThreadFunc`, or the thread procedure that will be called in remote process:

- Most certainly `AfterThreadFunc` method will be optimized out of the Release build, so the size of `ThreadFunc` procedure will not be set correctly.
- Many compilers doing a Debugger build will add additional debugger checks to methods, which will most certainly make `ThreadFunc` crash in the injected remote process.

I thought of the easiest way to address what I stated above, but unfortunately there seems to be no better way other than to use assembler. Obviously, due to that, the following applies only to 32-bit processes.

Here's my C implementation of Remy Lebeau's solution (sorry, I don't use Delphi.)

First struct definitions:

```
#define  MAX_BUF_SIZE (512)
typedef LRESULT     (WINAPI *SENDMESSAGE)(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM);

struct INJDATA
{
    //IMPORTANT: If ANY of this struct members are changed, you will need to
                 adjust the assembler code below!

    SENDMESSAGE     fnSendMessage;  // pointer to user32!SendMessage
    HWND    hwnd;
    UINT    msg;
    WPARAM  wParam;
    BYTE    arrLPARAM[MAX_BUF_SIZE];

};
```

Then collect static pointers once when the app starts, no need to do it every time our method is invoked. For that move them all into its own `struct`:

```
struct SENDMSG_INJ_INFO{
    SENDMESSAGE fnSendMessageRemote;
    int ncbSzFnSendMessageRemote;           //Size of 'fnSendMessageRemote' in BYTEs

    HMODULE hUser32;
    SENDMESSAGE pfnSendMessage;             //SendMessage API pointer

    SENDMSG_INJ_INFO() :
        fnSendMessageRemote(NULL)
        , ncbSzFnSendMessageRemote(0)
    {
        hUser32 = ::LoadLibrary(L"user32");
        pfnSendMessage = hUser32 ? (SENDMESSAGE)GetProcAddress(hUser32, "SendMessageW") : NULL;

        int ncbSz = 0;
        SENDMESSAGE pfn = NULL;

        __asm
        {
            //Get sizes & offsets
            mov         eax, lbl_code_begin
            mov         dword ptr [pfn], eax
            mov         eax, lbl_code_after
            sub         eax, lbl_code_begin
            mov         dword ptr [ncbSz], eax
            jmp         lbl_code_after

lbl_code_begin:
            //Thread proc that will be executed in remote process
            mov         eax,dword ptr [esp+4] 
            mov         edx,dword ptr [eax+0Ch] 
            lea         ecx,[eax+10h] 
            push        ecx  
            mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax+8] 
            push        edx  
            mov         edx,dword ptr [eax+4] 
            mov         eax,dword ptr [eax] 
            push        ecx  
            push        edx  
            call        eax  

            ret

lbl_code_after:
        }

        ncbSzFnSendMessageRemote = ncbSz;
        fnSendMessageRemote = pfn;
    }
    ~SENDMSG_INJ_INFO()
    {
        if(hUser32)
        {
            ::FreeLibrary(hUser32);
            hUser32 = NULL;
        }
    }
};
```

Now the question for people that don't know assembler is how to get that procedure in `asm`. It's actually pretty easy. Put the following method into your `Release` build (note `Release`, it's important) and then set a debugger breakpoint on `prototypeThreadFuncSendMsg` call and copy the asm from it:

```
//.h hile
LRESULTDWORD __declspec(noinline) prototypeThreadFuncSendMsg(INJDATA *pData);

//.cpp file
LRESULT prototypeThreadFuncSendMsg(INJDATA *pData)
{
    // There must be less than a page-worth of local
    // variables used in this function.
    return pData->fnSendMessage( pData->hwnd, pData->msg, pData->wParam, (LPARAM) pData->arrLPARAM );
}
```

The important point is to make compiler not to inline it. For Visual Studio I added `__declspec(noinline)` for that.

Then we need a global variable to store our pointers:

```
//Define on a global scope
SENDMSG_INJ_INFO sii;
```

And now the method that calls it all (just a slightly adjusted code from the [original post](http://www.dcsoft.com/private/sendmessageremote.cpp) -- I just added a couple of error checks & a timeout):

```
//.h file
static BOOL SendMessageTimeoutRemote(DWORD dwProcessId, HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPVOID pLPARAM, size_t sizeLParam, DWORD dwmsMaxWait = 5 * 1000, LRESULT* plOutSendMessageReturn = NULL);

//.cpp file
BOOL SendMessageTimeoutRemote(DWORD dwProcessId, HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPVOID pLPARAM, size_t sizeLParam, DWORD dwmsMaxWait, LRESULT* plOutSendMessageReturn)
{
    //'dwmsMaxWait' = max number of ms to wait for result, or INFINITE to wait for as long as needed
    //'plOutSendMessageReturn' = if not NULL, will receive the value returned from calling SendMessage API in remote process
    //RETURN:
    //          = TRUE if message was sent successfully (check returned value in 'plOutSendMessageReturn')
    BOOL bRes = FALSE;

    HANDLE      hProcess = NULL;    // the handle of the remote process
    HINSTANCE   hUser32 = NULL;
    INJDATA     *pDataRemote = NULL;    // the address (in the remote process) where INJDATA will be copied to;
    DWORD       *pCodeRemote = NULL;    // the address (in the remote process) where ThreadFunc will be copied to;
    HANDLE      hThread = NULL; // the handle to the thread executing the remote copy of ThreadFunc;
    DWORD       dwThreadId = 0;

    DWORD       dwNumBytesXferred = 0; // number of bytes written/read to/from the remote process;
    LRESULT     lSendMessageReturn = 0xFFFFFFFF;


    __try
    {
        if (sii.pfnSendMessage == NULL)
            __leave;

        if(sizeLParam < 0 ||
            sizeLParam > MAX_BUF_SIZE)
        {
            //Too much data
            ASSERT(NULL);
            __leave;
        }

        // Initialize INJDATA
        INJDATA DataLocal =
        { 
            sii.pfnSendMessage,
            hwnd, msg, wParam
        };

        memcpy ( DataLocal.arrLPARAM, pLPARAM, sizeLParam );

        // Copy INJDATA to Remote Process
        hProcess = OpenProcess ( PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |
                                 PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_READ,
                                 FALSE, dwProcessId);
        if ( !hProcess )
            __leave;

        // 1. Allocate memory in the remote process for INJDATA
        // 2. Write a copy of DataLocal to the allocated memory
        pDataRemote = (INJDATA*) VirtualAllocEx( hProcess, 0, sizeof(INJDATA), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE );
        if (pDataRemote == NULL)
            __leave;
        if(!WriteProcessMemory( hProcess, pDataRemote, &DataLocal, sizeof(INJDATA), (SIZE_T *)&dwNumBytesXferred ) ||
            dwNumBytesXferred != sizeof(INJDATA))
            __leave;


        // Calculate the number of bytes that ThreadFunc occupies
        int cbCodeSize = sii.ncbSzFnSendMessageRemote;
        if(cbCodeSize <= 0)
            __leave;
        if(!sii.fnSendMessageRemote)
            __leave;

        // 1. Allocate memory in the remote process for the injected ThreadFunc
        // 2. Write a copy of ThreadFunc to the allocated memory
        pCodeRemote = (PDWORD) VirtualAllocEx( hProcess, 0, cbCodeSize, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE );       
        if (pCodeRemote == NULL)
            __leave;
        if(!WriteProcessMemory( hProcess, pCodeRemote, sii.fnSendMessageRemote, cbCodeSize, (SIZE_T *)&dwNumBytesXferred ) ||
            dwNumBytesXferred != cbCodeSize)
            __leave;


        // Start execution of remote ThreadFunc
        hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, NULL, 0, 
                (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) pCodeRemote,
                pDataRemote, 0 , &dwThreadId);
        if (hThread == NULL)
            __leave;

        //Wait for thread to finish
        DWORD dwR = WaitForSingleObject(hThread, dwmsMaxWait);
        if(dwR == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
        {
            //Get return value
            if(GetExitCodeThread(hThread, (PDWORD)&lSendMessageReturn))
            {
                // Copy LPARAM back (result is in it)
                if(ReadProcessMemory( hProcess, pDataRemote->arrLPARAM, pLPARAM, sizeLParam, (SIZE_T *)&dwNumBytesXferred) &&
                    dwNumBytesXferred == sizeLParam)
                {
                    //Done
                    bRes = TRUE;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    __finally 
    {
        //Clean up
        if ( pDataRemote != 0 )
        {
            VirtualFreeEx( hProcess, pDataRemote, 0, MEM_RELEASE );
            pDataRemote = NULL;
        }

        if ( pCodeRemote != 0 )
        {
            VirtualFreeEx( hProcess, pCodeRemote, 0, MEM_RELEASE );
            pCodeRemote = NULL;
        }

        if ( hThread != NULL ) 
        {
            CloseHandle(hThread);
            hThread = NULL;
        }

        if ( hProcess )
        {
            CloseHandle (hProcess);
            hProcess = NULL;
        }
    }

    if(plOutSendMessageReturn)
        *plOutSendMessageReturn = lSendMessageReturn;

    return bRes;
}
```

And finally my requested method to set the date/time:

```
BOOL SetDateCtrlRemote(HWND hWnd, SYSTEMTIME* pSt)
{
    //Set date/time in the DateTimePicker control with 'hWnd' in another process
    //'pSt' = local date/time to set
    //RETURN:
    //      = TRUE if done
    BOOL bRes = FALSE;

    NMDATETIMECHANGE dtc = {0};

    if(hWnd &&
        pDt &&
        pSt)
    {
        memcpy(&dtc.st, pSt, sizeof(*pSt));

        //Get process ID for Digi
        DWORD dwProcID = 0;
        ::GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &dwProcID);
        if(dwProcID)
        {
            int nCntID = ::GetDlgCtrlID(hWnd);
            if(nCntID)
            {
                HWND hParentWnd = ::GetParent(hWnd);
                if(hParentWnd)
                {
                    dtc.dwFlags = GDT_VALID;
                    dtc.nmhdr.hwndFrom = hWnd;
                    dtc.nmhdr.code = DTN_DATETIMECHANGE;
                    dtc.nmhdr.idFrom = nCntID;

                    LRESULT lRes = 0;

                    //First change the control itself -- use 2 sec timeout
                    if(SendMessageTimeoutRemote(dwProcID, hWnd, DTM_SETSYSTEMTIME, GDT_VALID, &dtc.st, sizeof(dtc.st), 2 * 1000, &lRes) &&
                        lRes != 0)
                    {
                        //Then need to send notification to the parent too!
                        if(SendMessageTimeoutRemote(dwProcID, hParentWnd, WM_NOTIFY, dtc.nmhdr.idFrom, &dtc, sizeof(dtc), 2 * 1000))
                        {
                            //Done
                            bRes = TRUE;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return bRes;
}
```

I know it's a lot of code, but once you do it once, it will all work and you can reuse that method for other calls.

Again, thanks to [Remy Lebeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau)!

Comment: 1) `AfterThreadFunc()` won't be optimized out, because there is code referencing it.  But using assembly can make the code a little more streamlined and safer (of course, you might need to write an x64 version as well). 2) The original code (not my code) was already written in C, all I did was translate it to Delphi. 3) as I mentioned in my code, VCL does not use control IDs, so `GetDlgCtrlID()` will always return 0, so you need to remove the `if(nCntID)` check.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Re.1: it might be just the Visual Studio thing, because that's what it did there for me, plus it inlined `ThreadFunc()`. Re.3: The app I'm working with has control IDs but they change every time the app runs. I honestly did not expect that. Is it something specific for VCL?

Comment: Again, VCL does not use control IDs **at all** (so you cannot use `GetDlgItem...()`, `SetDlgItem...()`, or `SendDlgItemMessage()`, either). They are not even assigned at runtime.  VCL does not use dialog resources for UIs like VS does.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Hmm. Strange, I'm checking this `TDateTimePicker` control with Spy++ in the app I'm working with and it does have non-0 Control ID, which changes with every run.

Comment: The VCL does not assign control IDs. `TWinControl.CreateWindowHandle()` sets the `hMenu` parameter of `CreateWindowEx()` to 0. I just did a test, and calling `GetDlgCtrlID()` on any VCL control is returning the specified HWND as the ID. That is not documented behavior, and is not mentioned in tutorials (I found an [online forum post from 2003](http://www.delphigroups.info/3/60/8564.html) that mentions it), so don't rely on it. Treat the returned ID as an arbitrary value, unless you know for sure that a given child HWND was created as part of a dialog resource (which VCL UIs are not).

Comment: @Remy - VCL sets dialog ids to window handles in InitWndProc for child windows. It has always been this way.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: interesting, never noticed that before. Sure enough, I checked the VCL source all the way back to BCB/Delphi 5, and it does indeed do that. Learned something new after 17 years of using the VCL and digging through its source code.